# Api works fine when checked with postman. Android studio gives null point exception error in response body

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I am new to android studio so any help would of great use.
I am using retrofit and trying to signup a user on my android application. 
This is the error which I was getting. In which part of the code am I going wrong or have created some mistake as I am only getting Null pointer exception means the API is not correct but it works fine with postman

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String okhttp3.ResponseBody.string()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.my_app.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:92)
```

Below is the attached activity.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFormBackground" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@color/colorFormBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_password"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_name"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextMobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_mobile"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:hint="mobile"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="7dp"
        android:text="Already have an Account?\nClick to Login"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFormBackground"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSignUp"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFormBackground" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.my_app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private EditText editTextEmail, editTextPassword, editTextName, editTextMobile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextName = findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextMobile = findViewById(R.id.editTextMobile);

        findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUp).setOnClickListener(this);

        findViewById(R.id.textViewLogin).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void userSignUp() {
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
        String mobile = editTextMobile.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            editTextEmail.setError("Email is required");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            editTextEmail.setError("Enter a valid email");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            editTextPassword.setError("Password required");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (password.length() < 6) {
            editTextPassword.setError("Password should be at least 6 character long");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            editTextName.setError("Name required");
            editTextName.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (mobile.isEmpty()) {
            editTextMobile.setError("Mobile required");
            editTextMobile.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
        Call<ResponseBody> call = RetrofitClient
                .getInstance()
                .getApi()
                .createUser(email, password, name, mobile);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                try {
                    System.out.println(response.errorBody());
                    String s=response.body().string();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }




            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        });

}




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonSignUp:
                userSignUp();
                break;
            case R.id.textViewLogin:



                break;
    }
}
}
```

Below is the attached Api.java file

```
package com.example.my_app;

import retrofit2.Call;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface Api {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("createuser")
    Call<ResponseBody> createUser(
            @Field("email") String email,
            @Field("password") String password,
            @Field("name") String name,
            @Field("mobile") String mobile
    );

}
```

Comment: add ResponseBody  to your question from postman

Comment: also add your ResponseBody class

Comment: Your response is returning null, likely because the `ResponseBody` does not match the JSON returned from the API. To confirm, please post an example of the JSON API and the `ResponseBody`. Alternatively you can use the AndroidStudio plugin "GsonFormat" to generate a JSON Model automatically.

Comment: I am getting a 401 error.